# Windows could not start Atlassian Confluence service on Local Computer?

Tags: java, confluence

I run a single user instance of **Atlassian Confluence** and yesterday I upgraded to version **5.5**.  My Confluence wiki worked fine after the upgrade.  However, after a reboot when I tried to access my wiki using its usual URL I received this error:

```
This page can’t be displayed

• Make sure the web address http://localhost:8090 is correct. 

• Look for the page with your search engine. 

• Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

I checked to see if the Atlassian Confluence service had started, and it has not, so I tried to do that manually.  I received this more helpful error message:

```
Windows could not start the Atlassian Confluence service on Local Computer.

Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My sys admin skills are few but I uncovered https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows which
led me to try changing the JAVA_HOME system environment variable from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_35` to `C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_35` but this did not help (even after a reboot).

I am reasonably sure that a Java upgrade I accepted recently may be involved in this error.  I am using Windows 7 SP1 and have these subfolders present in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java:

- jdk1.6.0_35
- jre7

Can anyone advise on whether they know a solution for how to restore my Atlassian Confluence 5.5 to a working condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug introduced in v5.5 - see [CONF-33492](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-33492).

The linked issue includes a simple registry hack workaround.